# Why do I see this port as a leave? How to know if I really can get rid of it?

Tags: macports

Once I've installed an svn, I need it.

```
$ port echo requested
...
subversion                     @1.8.1_3
```

As I understand, this port is important for subversion:

```
$ port echo depof:subversion
...
curl-ca-bundle
```

Then I take a look on what is important for it:

```
$ port echo depof:curl-ca-bundle  
perl5
```

So as a conclusion, svn needs perl5, right?
But:

```
$ port echo leaves
...
perl5                          @5.12.4_0+perl5_12
```

How is that possible? Doesn't `leaves: installed ports that are unrequested and have no dependents.` mean I don't need perl5? So I need it for svn to work or not?

Comment: Probably because you're running Mac OS X 10.8 which has Perl 5 installed by default.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm on 10.8.4

Comment: Type `which perl` at the command line to confirm.

Comment: Already uninstalled all leaves. `/usr/bin/perl`

Comment: @PaulR macports uses its own perl and not Apple's so that it know exactly which version it is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl is a build dependency for `curl-ca-bundle`. Build dependencies are only needed at build time and can be removed afterwards, which makes `perl5` a leaf in your case.